# MVC Model Binding with Dynamic Collection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, collections, model-binding

According to the seminal Scott Hanselman article on the complexities of the [ASP.NET Wire Format for Model Binding to Arrays, Lists, Collections, Dictionaries](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx):

> We read in the properties by looking for **`parameterName[index].PropertyName`**
>   The index must be zero-based and unbroke

So this HTML:

```html
<input type="text" name="People[0].FirstName" value="George" />
<input type="text" name="People[1].FirstName" value="Abraham" />
<input type="text" name="People[2].FirstName" value="Thomas" />
```

Which will post like this:

[image: Post Data - People%5B0%5D.FirstName=George&People%5B1%5D.FirstName=Abraham&People%5B2%5D.FirstName=Thomas]

However, if I load a new person into my model over AJAX, I lose the context for building that person into the model and get the following output:

```html
<input type="text" name="FirstName" value="New" />
```

[image: Post Data - People%5B0%5D.FirstName=George&People%5B1%5D.FirstName=Abraham&People%5B2%5D.FirstName=Thomas&FirstName=John]

Which won't get picked up by the model binder.

**Q**: *How can I preserve the expression tree when dynamically adding new elements over AJAX?*

#### Here's an MVCE

**Model: `/Model/Person.cs`**

```cs
public class PersonViewModel
{
    public List<Person> People { get; set; }
}
public class Person
{
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String LastName { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller: `Controllers/PersonController.cs`**

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Person> people = new List<Person> {
        new Person { FirstName = "George" , LastName = "Washington"},
        new Person { FirstName = "Abraham" , LastName = "Lincoln"},
        new Person { FirstName = "Thomas" , LastName = "Jefferson"},
    };
    PersonViewModel model = new PersonViewModel() {People = people};
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(PersonViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}

public ActionResult AddPerson(String first, String last)
{
    Person newPerson = new Person { FirstName = first, LastName = last };
    return PartialView("~/Views/Person/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml", newPerson);
}
```

**View: `Views/Person/Index.cshtml`**

```html
@model PersonViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    <table id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.People.First().FirstName)</th>
                <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.People.First().LastName)</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.People.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.People[i])
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Add Person" id="add"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#add").click(function() {
        var url = "@Url.Action("AddPerson")?" + $.param({ first: "", last: "" });
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: url,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#table tbody").append(data);
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**View: `Views/Person/EditorTemplates/Person.cshtml`**

```html
@model Person

<tr>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
    <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
</tr>
```

**NOTE**: There are other complexities when deleting an item that I'm not looking to address here per se.  I'd just like to add an element and know that it belongs in a nested context alongside other properties.

Comment: MVC's helpers are great until you start doing more advanced things with collections - once you get to that point you're better off taking control of the markup generation yourself. Stick a count somewhere in the DOM and pick it up in your JS, then you can build the (model-bindable) markup manually when you add a new item.

Comment: If you wanting to dynamically add (and remove) collection items in the view, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options. Side note - you cannot use `EditorFor()` in this case, but the correct usage would have been just `@Html.EditorFor(m => model.People)` - not inside a loop - the method accepts `IEnumerable<T>` and will generate the correct htlml for each item in the collection

Comment: For an implementation using the client side template approach, refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wqE6Rb). For an example of the `BeginCollectionItem()` implemetation, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [install](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItem/) the [`Html.BeginCollectionItem`](https://github.com/danludwig/BeginCollectionItem) utility like this:

```
PM> Install-Package BeginCollectionItem
```

Then wrap your collection item partial view like this:

```html
@model Person
<tr>
    @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("people"))
    {
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName)</td>
    }
</tr>
```

Which will generate a GUID-driven collection like this:

```html
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="people.index" autocomplete="off" 
                     value="132bfe2c-75e2-4f17-b54b-07e011971d78">
    <td><input class="text-box single-line" type="text" value="Abraham"
                 id="people_132bfe2c-75e2-4f17-b54b-07e011971d78__FirstName" 
               name="people[132bfe2c-75e2-4f17-b54b-07e011971d78].FirstName"></td>
    <td><input class="text-box single-line"  type="text" value="Lincoln"
                 id="people_132bfe2c-75e2-4f17-b54b-07e011971d78__LastName"  
               name="people[132bfe2c-75e2-4f17-b54b-07e011971d78].LastName"></td>            
</tr>
```

Now we get posted form data that look like this:

[image: Form Data - with GUIDs]

This leverages the **DefaultModelBinder** which allows for **Non-Sequential Indices** as [explained by Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/):

> The good news is that by introducing an extra hidden input, you can allow for arbitrary indices. Just provide a hidden input with the `.Index` suffix for each item we need to bind to the list. The name of each of these hidden inputs is the same, which will give the model binder a nice collection of indices to look for when binding to the list.

Right away, your model should build just fine, but you'll also be able to add and remove items as well.

**Further Reading**

- [A Partial View passing a collection using the Html.BeginCollectionItem helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40541892/1366033)
- [Submit same Partial View called multiple times data to controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28081308/1366033)
- [Model Binding To A List - Phil Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)