# how to add textbox for modal with one to many relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have two models "user" (id,username,address) and "sales" (id,descriprion,userid)

user can have multiple sales (one to many relationship)

and i want to add user information from mvc razor form and i also want to send sales information to controller from my form.

my question is what is the best way to do this task

I am using grid and a small form to add sales in a grid and want to post that grid with user information. i dont know how to do this.

please suggest me the best way to do this task. or the way that i am using how to post sales also with user information.

Here is the way i want to post this form

[Click Image to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KBzg.png)

Comment: Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options. And [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a more detailed example using the `BeginCollectionItem` method

Answer (score 0):

If you need to insert multi description for each user I think you have to create a list of hidden input(I use jquery you can choose another plugin or pure javascripts)

```
<form>
    <input id="username" name="username" />
    <input type="button" value="Add" id="btnAdd" />
    <table id="saleTable">
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <div id="inputContainer">
    </div>
</form>

<script>
    var index = 0;
    $("#btnAdd").on("click", function () {
        var saleDesc = $("#saleDesc").val();
        $("#inputContainer").append('<input type="hidden" value="' + saleDesc + '" name="Sales[' + index + '].Description" />');
        $("#saleTable tbody").append('<tr><td> ' + saleDesc + '</td></tr>');
        index++;
    });
</script>
```

the code above will work with following ViewModel

```
public class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public List<Sale> Sales { get; set; }
}

public class Sale
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And after you click on Submit button you receive data in controller

```
 public ActionResult Receive(User model)
 {
     //Save data...
     return View()
 }
```