# Asp.net MVC 4.5 Add Object to List in ViewModel with EditorFor, Button Click

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 application. I want to add objects to a `List<T>` dynamically on a button click, using a `@Html.EditorFor` and send the data to the Controller with a Form submit.

However, my problem, only the 1st element of the populated list gets sent to the controller when I submit my Form.

The area in my view where I add Elements looks like this:

```
<div id="addTarget" data-target="@Url.Action("AddTarget", "Offer")">

    @for(var i = 0; i < Model.Targets.Count(); i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Targets[i])
    }
</div>
```

My Controller looks like that:

```
...

public OfferVm NewOffer { get; set; } = new OfferVm();

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // ...here I add my first initial target to OfferVm
    NewOffer.Targets.Add(new TargetVm());

    return View(NewOffer);
}

public ActionResult AddTarget()
{
    // ...here I add a target to my NewOffer
    NewOffer.Targets.Add(new TargetVm());
    return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/TargetVm.cshtml");
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(OfferVm offerVM)
{
   //... here only 1 target is in my offerVM
}
```

My OfferVm class looks like this:

```
public class OfferVm
{
    public OfferVm()
    {
        this.Targets = new List<TargetVm>();
    }

    public List<TargetVm> Targets { get; set; }
}
```

Do you have an idea how I can add a new target to my NewOffer.Targets List, and get the data in my controller, when I post the form?

Comment: You cannot use `EditorFor()` - and your generating identical `name` attributes for your 'new' `TargetVm` (the `DefaultModelBinder` only reads the first value and ignores the rest). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thanks for your answer! It gave me a good idea on how to solve this issue. As I'm limited on three "Targets" I just create them in the constructor, and hide two of them with javascript. Have a nice day!

Comment: A terrible way to handle it

Comment: And your not understanding the `EditorFor()` method anyway - its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Targets)` - no loop - the method generates the correct html for each item in the collection.

Comment: Actually you are right, it doesn't really work with EditorFor(). I just tried Html.Partial(), but then I have an empty collection anyways, because the fields are not binded properly. I guess I will try option 2 of your posting... thanks sir!

Comment: I would suggest based on your current knowledge, that you start with Option 1. And refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a more complete example

Comment: Thanks Stephen, it seems to work! only one problem left, the field validation doesn't work anymore. I used the [required] attribute for 2 properties on my TargetVm. Do you have a clue?

Comment: You obviously did did not read either of my answers I linked to :) - you need to re-parse the validator

Comment: haha indeed, unfortunately I missed on that detail. Thanks for your help Stephen!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason only the first `TargetVm` in your collection is being bound in the POST method, is that your `AddTarget()` method your calling to add a new item is generating form controls with `name` that are identical to those your have previously generated. Assuming `TargetVm` has a property named `ID`, then your have multiple elements with

```
<input ... name="Targets[0].ID" ... />
```

and the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first name/value pair from the request, and ignores any subsequent duplicate names. In order to bind to a collection, your `name` attributes need to have indexers that start at zero and be consecutive.

```
<input ... name="Targets[0].ID" ... /> // first TargetVM
<input ... name="Targets[1].ID" ... /> // second TargetVM
<input ... name="Targets[2].ID" ... /> // third TargetVM
```

Note you can also include an extra input for each item in the collection -  `<input type="hidden" name="Targets.Index value="xx" />` (where `xx` is the value of the indexer) to bind non-consecutive indexers as discussed in [Model Binding To A List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/).

Using the `EditorFor()` method will not work in the case where your dynamically adding new collection items, unless you were to use javascript to update the value of the indexer in the `name` attribute when its added.

Solutions include using a javascript MVVM framework such as [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), using the `BeginCollectionItem()` helper, or using a client side template and javascript to dynamically add new form controls. The latter two options are discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308), and a more complete example using `BeginCollectionItem()` is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response! Yes, the `BeginCollectionItem()` did the trick!