# How to create web API POST method for Ont-to-Many Relationships?

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api

I am creating web API for Order.
in which two tables I have created

1)Tbl_Order have columns-

```
Order_ID     -Primary Key,
Employee_ID,
TotalBill,
```

2)Tbl_OrderMenu have columns-

```
OrderMenuID    -Primary Key,
Order_ID       -Foreign Key from Tbl_Order,
MenuName,
Quantity
```

the relationship between tables is one-to-many i.e. Tbl_Order(1)-to-Tbl_OrderMenu(* or Many).

How can I create Web API to POST method to create Data at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, in this case, first you need to add data to **Tbl_Order** table. Then you can add as many data to **Tbl_OrderMenu** table, by taking Order_ID from the first table. Hope you understood this.

Create a class which should include both the table. For example,

```
public class myCombinedClass
{
 public int Order_ID {get;set;}
 public int Employee_ID {get;set;}
 public string TotalBill {get;set;}
 public List<Tbl_OrderMenu> OrderMenu { get; set; }
}
```

In your API Controller method, you can write like this,

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(myCombinedClass myData)
{
 if(myData.id == 0)
  {
    // This is a new entry to Tbl_Order.
    Tbl_Order orderObject = new Tbl_Order();
    orderObject.Employee_ID = myData.Employee_ID;
    orderObject.TotalBill = myData.TotalBill;
    _ctx.Tbl_Order.Add(orderObject);
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
  }
 else
  {
   //You just need to update the Tbl_Order. I mean, here you are adding 
   //data to Tbl_OrderMenu table with  Order_ID.
   var OrderMenuData = _ctx.Tbl_OrderMenu.where(m=>m.Order_ID == 
                       myData.id).FirstOrDefault(); 
   OrderMenuData.Order_ID = myData.id;     
   OrderMenuData.MenuName = myData.OrderMenu.MenuName;
   OrderMenuData.Quantity = myData.OrderMenu.Quantity;
   _ctx.Entry(OrderMenuData).State=System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
   _ctx.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

**Note**: See here, _ctx is the context class, that you need to add in this controller/method.

```
Ex: MyDBContext _ctx = new MyDBContext();
```

I have written an answer same like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42870219/how-to-post-and-catch-a-view-model-with-a-parent-object-and-list-of-child-object). Go through that. Check how I'm passing data to both the table in ajax method.

Comment: actually, I am new to Web API.can you please elaborate what will come in Post Method.

Comment: thank you @BasantaMatia. it works for me for 50%. but I want to add data in **Tbl_OrderMenu** on behalf on **OrderID**. I mean Tbl_OrderMenu should contain Data respect to OrderID.

Comment: thank you @BasantaMatia . it works for me for 50%. but I want to add data in **Tbl_OrderMenu** on behalf on **OrderID**. I mean Tbl_OrderMenu should contain Data respect to OrderID. Consider data in **Tbl_Order** is : **(OrderID:1,EmpolyeeID:101, TotalBill:10)** then data in **Tbl_OrderMenu** shhould like **(OrderMenuId:1,OrderID:1,Menu:Bread)** should be added

Comment: That is what I did in my answer. U just need to understand the code properly. U need to pass data for Tbl_OrderMenu table including OrderID. Check where u are getting error and try to debug. If it solve ur problem plz don't forget to mark as answer.

Comment: sir i do as per your instructions but it not working as per my requirement. by using your code i can only create record in **Tbl_Order** table.there is no record in **Tbl_Order,menu** . please help me.

Comment: I have attached a link in my answer, did u check that 1 ? It's d complete answer. Bdw can u tell me from where u are calling the API method? How u are calling this API method, can u post the code here.

Comment: i post code as   {
   "Tbl_OrderMenu":[{
    "MenuID": 1,
        "MenuName": "Idli",
        }],   
    "NumberOfItems": 1,
    "TotalBill": 20.0,    
  }

Comment: That's fine. Please chick on d link I have mentioned in my answer. U can see how the data u need to pass. The way u r passing data, it's wrong. And just put a break point in ur API method and check. Plz check that link.

Comment: sir I visit your link but I can't do what I want.

Comment: your code generates record in **Tbl_Order**.please tell me how to add record in **Tbl_OrderMenu** what i want to do.

Comment: If u have written the API method exactly the way I mentioned in my answer, then post ur json data like this [{Order_ID:1,   Tbl_OrderMenu: [{ Order_ID:1,MenuName:"Manish",Quantity:1}]}] If OrderMenuID is auto generated then no need else include that one too inside Tbl_OrderMenu:[{}] Put a breakpoint n check in ur API method.

Comment: sir Order_ID is also autogenerated. System must able to set OrderID for records in Tbl_OrderMenu table

Comment: Order_ID will b auto generated for Tbl_Order table, not for Tbl_OrderMenu table. So u need to pass it the way I mentioned in my previous comment. The orderId should b present in db before u saving data for 2nd table.

Comment: ok sir, Finally got what i want. Thank you so much. i do mistakes while post data.