# ASP.NET Core MVC add/remove dynamic content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic, asp.net-core

I'm currently developing a system which manages work times and analyze them. Therefore I need to add several *Time-Stamps* once and add/remove some input field dynamically.

The ViewModel looks like:

```
public class CreateWorkDayViewModel
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CreateStampModel> Stamps { get; set; }
}

public class CreateStampModel
{
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

How to do this with the razer syntax including validation?

I'm developing with Visual Studio Version 15.2 and the latest stable MVC version.

**EDIT (17.05.17):**
*What I've done so far:*

I added a jQuery based mechanism to add/remove rows dynamically.
[Click for the mechanism](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-table-row-creation-and-deletion)
My problem is, that in the part of where I'm adding the rows(at JS line 4) I can't use the razor syntax because this html code is inserted at runtime by jQuery.
I also tried it with the old way and used instead of `asp-for` `name`. This works for the post data, but to fill the project drop-down selection I need the data from the ViewModel and this is missing.

Comment: Share what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can't do this with razer. I'd recommend checking out knockout.js library. As for now, perhaps try loading the dropdown data from a hidden field or load it with ajax.

Comment: @AntonToshik I prefer to stay with ASP.NET Core MVC, because adding such a huge JS-Framework will blow up the time limit. Currently im working on this approach: [Click here](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43794893/how-to-copy-table-row-with-dropdownlist-in-with-jquery/43796337#43796337

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman First, thanks for your reply. This approach will work, but isn't that clean way what I'm looking for. I found another approach what im actually trying on. If u're interested in [Check this](https://github.com/saad749/BeginCollectionItemCore)