# ASP.NET MVC 5 best practise form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

**Description:**
I have a form for user-friendly input:
[image: this is the form]

But i can't submit form in this way, coz my model for this form action looks like:

```
    public string Title { get; set; }  // First input
    public string Description { get; set; }  // Second input
    public string SportsmanId { get; set; }  // Not used
    public List<WorkoutExerciseParam> WorkoutExerciseParams { get; set; }  // Items, combined from list items (show on form screenshot)
    public SelectList AvailableSportsmans { get; set; }  // Dropdown list
```

So, if I can't submit, I wrote JS code to construct and post consistent model:

```
$(document)
        .ready(function() {
            $("#submit").click(function() {
                var exerciseList = [];
                /* Assemble exerciseList from OL and UL items */
                var title = $("input#Title").val();
                var description = $("input#Description").val();
                var sportsmanId = $("select#SportsmanId").val();
                $.post('@Url.Action("Create", "Workout")',
                {
                    Title: title,
                    Description: description,
                    SportsmanId: sportsmanId,
                    WorkoutExerciseParams: exerciseList
                });
            });
        });
```

This code works fine, but I can't redirect after the action is done (like when I just submit the form):[image: code sample]

Then, I rewrite JS code so, that it constructs a new hidden form with hidden input and submit it. But I don't know how to create the list of inputs (List from first code sample).

**Question:**

What is the best practice to submit data to ASP.NET Controller's Action throw JS that I can use RedirectToAction() and View() methods?
Do I need construct form (how can I do a list of objects) or how handle RedirectToAction() and View() method in JS?

Comment: Use a normal submit (and what makes you think your model has anything to do with not being able to use a normal submit)

Comment: @StephenMuecke coz normal submit doesn't convert UL and OL to List<...>

Comment: Your `<ol>` and `<li>` are not posted - your form controls are, and you just have to name them correctly to bind to your model. Start by reading the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) (I recommend you use the `BeginCollectionItem()` method

Comment: @StephenMuecke so, i doen't know about this trick. Thanks. If you draw up your answer, I can mark it as correct and close the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be making a normal submit rather that ajax if you want to redirect (or be able to return the view and display validation errors if `ModelState` is invalid. There is no point using ajax, since ajax calls do not redirect.

You have not shown how your dynamically generating the inputs associated with your `WorkoutExerciseParam` collection, but they just need to be named correctly with indexers so that they will be bound by the `DefaultModelBinder`. The format needs to be

```
<input name="WorkoutExerciseParams[0].SomeProperty" .... />
<input name="WorkoutExerciseParams[0].AnotherProperty" .... />
<input name="WorkoutExerciseParams[1].SomeProperty" .... />
<input name="WorkoutExerciseParams[1].AnotherProperty" .... />
....
```

Your can generate this using javascript, but a better solution which gives you string type binding, client side validation for the dynamically added items and the ability to also delete items is to use the `BeginCollectionItem()` method as discussed in the answers to

- [Submit same Partial View called multiple times data to
  controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)
  and
- [A Partial View passing a collection using the
  Html.BeginCollectionItem
  helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/a-partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)