# How to bind List<T> on Form Post in ASP.Net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list

I have a model that contains a list property `List<EducationalBackground> EducationalBackground` and in the razor form I want the user to enter multiple institutions.

Model

```
public class Application
{
    ...
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]
    public List<EducationalBackground> EducationalBackground { get; set; }
    ...
    public Application() 
    {
        ...
        EducationalBackground = new List<Library.EducationalBackground>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Here is the class:

```
public class EducationalBackground
{
    public string InstituteName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

In the razor view I am trying like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.EducationalBackground[0].InstituteName, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but obviously it doesn't work because the list (`EducationalBackground`) is empty.

The user will have a "Add New Institution" button, so the initial list size is unknown

How do I properly accomplish this?

**UPDATE** Found my solution. Look for my post in the answer section

Comment: Refer the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for some options for dynamically adding and deleting collection items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. I can bind multiple `EducationalBackground` items like this

```
<input type="text" name="EducationalBackground[0].InstituteName" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="EducationalBackground[1].InstituteName" class="form-control" />
<input type="text" name="EducationalBackground[2].InstituteName" class="form-control" />
```

When the form posts, it will create a list of size 3

The user will have a "Add New Institution" button, so following this pattern, I will use JS to generate, on the fly, new `input` elements

Answer (score 2):

I am not quite sure what is the purpose of your view to edit a list of `EducationalBackground` or to add new ones. If you want to edit them you obviously need to take them from somewhere like database for example.

1. **Edit case:**

In the action you have:

```
EducationalBackground = new List<Library.EducationalBackground>
{
     new EducationalBackground(...),
     new EducationalBackground(...),
     new EducationalBackground(...),
     ..... //How many you want
}
```

In the view you have:

```
@foreach(var educationbackground in Model)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => educationbackground.InstituteName, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

2. **Add new ones.**

If you want to add new ones and as you have answered you may use simple html syntax to achieve that:
If you dont know the size of the list you want to add you may choose another way like in jQuery or angularjs to do this for you:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var size = 0;
        $("#btnAdd").click(function(){
             $(".someDiv").append("<input type='text' name='EducationalBackground["+size+"].InstituteName' class='form-control' />");
             size++;
        })
    })
</script>
```

**EDIT** for fiddle

Take a look at this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/voq5sLeh/)

Comment: This works if I have already a list and want to display them to the user. In my case I want the user to create the list of Institutions

Comment: The user will have a "Add New Institution" button, so the list size is unknown. Thanks

Comment: @JGeZau Should have posted the question with this explanation initially.

Comment: Yeap but referring to your explanation that I was thinking of. Anyway I made a small idea in jquery how to use it so you can try it out.

Comment: jQuery code looks good, that's what I was thinking on writing. Thanks!

Comment: @JGeZau look at the fiddle i edited and let me know if it correct one :)

Comment: This will not work (its creating duplicate `name` attributes and invalid html and will not bind when the form is submitted). Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) for an explanation of why you cannot use a `foreach` loop

Comment: @StephenMuecke you are correct. Already forgot that. Thanks for pointing it out :+1:

Answer (score 1):

Change the constructor of the `Application` class to this:

```
EducationalBackground = new List<Library.EducationalBackground>() 
{
    new Library.EducationalBackground()
};
```

Comment: This works if I only want to post one single list item, I want the user to add multiple Institutions.

Comment: I've just answered your question. If you want to user do this you will have their answers.