# C# MVC Razor form with a dynamic array of objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

So I'm trying to create a Invoice form. In this form I want to fill in some customer details and add products, all in the same form.
I created a static example of how I want it to look:
[image: mockup of this form]
The idea is to manually fill in a product, and if I want another product, I'd press the green plus glyphicon and add another product.
By clicking on the create button I want to submit this entire form with the customer details and the array/list of added products.

This is the code I have so far:

This is the view model that I use inside the view:

```
public class InvoiceViewModel
{
    public Enums.Gender Gender { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string HouseNumber { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public List<InvoiceItemViewModel> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}
```

This is the InvoiceItemViewModel that I use inside the partial view:

```
public class InvoiceItemViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Enums.UnitType UnitType { get; set; }
    public int Ammount { get; set; }
    public decimal PriceWithoutVAT { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Create view:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Gender, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Gender)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PostCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PostCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PostCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HouseNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HouseNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HouseNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StreetName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StreetName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StreetName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.City, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PhoneNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr />
        <h4>Products</h4>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">Name</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">Unit(s)</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">Ammount</div>
                <div class="col-md-2">Price</div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Invoice/InvoiceItem.cshtml")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Invoice/InvoiceItem.cshtml")
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-11">
                        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Invoice/InvoiceItem.cshtml")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: green;"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <br />
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

And this is the partial view for an invoice item:

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.UnitType)
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Ammount, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PriceWithoutVAT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
</div>
```

So my question is, how do I add multiple invoice items to my form that I can use in the controller when I submit? I'm afraid that it's going to be a lot of javascript DOM manipulations.

Comment: Refer also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a more complete example using `BeginCollectionItem()`

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden template of the row on your page, then on the click of plus button, you can read the innerhtml of the template and append to list container.

Sample code

```
var templatehtml = $('#template')[0].innerHTML;
var newhtml = templatehtml
        .replace(new RegExp('{{counter}}', 'g'), counter.toString())
        .replace('{{counter++}}', (Number(counter) + Number(1)).toString());
$('#container').append(newhtml);
```

This will get you started, however it's not the most optimal code and the recommended way is to use a template library like JSRender