# How to Insert multiple input with same name to database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I want to do insert multiple input with same name with entity framework.
I try this but not work

Model

```
public class Skill
    {
       [Key]
        public int skill_id { get; set; }


        public string skill_name { get; set; }
    }
```

View

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Skill

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <input type="text" name="skill_name[0]" id="skill_name[0]" />

    <input type="text" name="skill_name[1]" id="skill_name[1]" />

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

}
```

Controller

```
ProductContext db = new ProductContext();

[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(IList<Skill> skills)
    {
        foreach (var item in skills)
        {
            db.Skills.Add(skills);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("index");
    }
```

dbContext

```
public class ProductContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Skill> Skills { get; set; }
    }
```

How could I do? 
I find this
https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/
but  this tutorial does not have controller example for insert

Comment: Your model does not contain a property named `Skills`. What are you trying to bind to (your code makes no sense). Your model does not contain a collection item, and you only saving one object anyway.

Comment: Skills is from dbSet in dbContext

Comment: I know! But what are you trying to do here - insert multiple instance of `Skill`?

Comment: insert multiple instance to "skill_name" field in table Skill

Comment: I suggest you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) in detail to understand how to generate a view and bind to a collection. And if your wanting to dynamically add (and remove) items, then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)

Answer (score 1):

Change

`public string skill_name { get; set; }`

to

`public string[] skill_name { get; set; }`

Then Change the `Save` action method as follows

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(Skill skills)
{
    foreach (var skillName in skills.skill_name)
    { 
       Skill skill = new Skill(); 
       skill.skill_name = skillName;     
       db.Skills.Add(skill);
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
  return RedirectToAction("index");
}
```