# Identify the index of the button clicked while generating buttons using data repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, button

[image: I need to identify the row of the button click.Button is added dynamically throught a data repeater]

I need to identify the row of the button click.Button is added  dynamically throught a data repeater

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.lstUPC.Count; i++)
{
  <div class="col-md-1 addDelete">
    <input type="submit" value="+" class="form-control" name="UPCRowAdd" id="MPNet" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 addDelete">
    <input type="submit" value="-" class="form-control" name="UPCRowAdd" id="MPNet" />
  </div>      
}
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ItemSetup(ItemSetupModel itemSetupModel,  string UPCRowAdd, string command)
    {
        string queryString = string.Empty;
        if (UPCRowAdd == "+")
        {                     
                UPC upc = new UPC();
                itemSetupModel.lstUPC.Add(upc);                   
         }
    }
```

Model code

```
namespace PricingUpdates.Models
 {
   public class UPC
   {
    public string ItemNumberForUPC { get; set; }
    public string GCOwner { get; set; }
    public string GCFeeItem { get; set; }
    public string GCBranded { get; set; }
    public string query { get; set; }

  }
  public class ItemSetupModel
  {
  public StoreSelectionModel storeSelectionForUPC { get; set; }
  public List<UPC> lstUPC { get; set; }  
  } 
}
```

I have the button being generated dynamically ie based on the lstUPCCount(a list).Now whenever a button is clicked i need to identify which position or the index of the button clicked.How can i identify that.

Comment: Show your `ValidateDetailsForSub()` function (you can just add `data-index="@i` attribute to your button but its unclear why you want the index of the item in the collection - it suggests you have basic design problem)

Comment: And as a side note, `id="MPNet` means you ave duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html.

Comment: If i don't index is there any other way to identify the button which is clicked in the repeating elements.

Comment: That depends on what your code is doing (which is why I asked your to show it). You can of course do this in the normal fashion by giving your buttons a class name and then using `$('.yourClassName').click(function() { var theButton = $(this); ....});` but we do not know what you want to do with it.

Comment: I need to keep adding buttons row wise based on the items in the list.So each item in a list will have a button against it in UI. Each button add would help to add the new value in the list and delete button would remove item from the list.So accordingly the elements in the uI will also be removed.So i need to identify which row of the button is click to remove that row of elements alone

Comment: Don't tell me in comments. Edit your question to explain what your doing (and why) and show your code!

Comment: It also makes no sense why you are repeatedly adding `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SearchIndex)` inside your loop

Comment: I have edited the post to show controller code.I added hidden field to check if i can find the index by setting a value in hidden field.

Comment: I meant your `ValidateDetailsForSub()` script :)  And your POST method makes no sense in relationship to your view code (you have not shown the relevant parts of the view that would bind to any of those parameters except for the `string UPCRowAdd` parameter)

Comment: ValidateDetailsForSub() dosent contain anything i am trying to find how i can get index in the javascript function based on which row button has been clicked.

Comment: Based on my previous comments - `<input .... class="add" data-index="@i">` and `$('.add').click(function() { var index = $(this).data('index'); ..... });` But why you want the index of the item in the collection is not clear (and it certainly does not have any relationship to your POST method).

Comment: I just want to identify in a series of buttons in repeater which button was clicked in the UI.I thought i can do it through index.I am not aware of any other solution.If you have a better solution can you please help me.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do with your code (you have not explained anything in your question about that), so impossible to help any further

Comment: I have added the ui.The UI contains buttons with '+' and '-'.Now this button keps increaing based on the list of items in the list.On the '+' button click i will increase the count of list.And '-' button to remove the elements in the list.So whenever  button is clicked i need to know which row of the button is clicked.

Comment: That image suggests you want to dynamically add and remove collection items in the view, in which case refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and for a more complete example using `BeginCollectionItem` refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)

Comment: Now i am dynamicaly adding using my code.Only thing remaining is to identify which row of the button is clicked.

Comment: The code your have shown can never work correctly. Read the links I gave you to understand how to do it correctly

Comment: In the example i see that there is only one class 
CashRecipientVM and so in the cshtml you are able to pass IEnumerable<CashRecipientVM>.
Also i see that for the entire collection only button is add button is there.

In my case in place of CashRecipientVM i have multiple view models and in one view model i can have multiple buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index to create the id of the controls and can get the id on click event.

ex.

```
    @Html.Button(m => m.SearchIndex, new { id = i + "_Click", @class = "btnToBeChecked" })


    <script>
    $(".btnToBeChecked").on("click",function(){
        // Here index of the button would be assigned to new variable like below.
        var indexofButton = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[0];
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: there is no  @Html.ButtonFor in mvc.

Comment: Edited. Hope It helped you

Comment: There is no `@Html.Button()` method in MVC either!