# ASP.NET MVC Form Models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that consists of rows similar to this:

```
@model  Models.Group

@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "CreateGroup", FormMethod.Post))
{
<form method="post">

<div class="row" id="user2">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName_2, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmail_2, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    &nbsp;
</div>
<div class="row" id="user3">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName_3, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserEmail_3, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg margin-right">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> Save
      </button>
   </div>
  </div>
</form>
}
```

With a model that currently looks like this:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string UserName_2 { get; set; }

    public string UserEmail_2 { get; set; }

    public string UserName_3 { get; set; }

    public string UserEmail_3 { get; set; }
}
```

How do I get my View to support something like this where I can be able to add more Users without having to hard code the values into my Group model:

```
public class Group
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Edit: Or is there a better way to send the information from my form to the controller than using a Model? I was trying to use FormCollection but that doesn't seem to have any data when I submit

Comment: Start by removing the invalid nested form (i.e. `<form method="post">`)

Comment: Are you wanting to dynamically add (and remove) `User` items in your view?

Comment: I would like to dynamically add and remove eventually.

Comment: Then the answer by Oleksii Aza is not suitable. For some options, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308), and for a detailed implementation using `BeginCollectionItem`, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892)

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into those now.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing users by index, model binding should pick it up.
The code would look like:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.Users.Length; i++)
{
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Users[i].Name, new { @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Users[i].Email, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: I think this looks right. Am I using a Model correctly here though? This page is a blank form where a user can enter names that I want to store into a list. This is the basic layout: https://i.imgur.com/TZD7WAP.png

Comment: I guess you should initiate a list of users so it contains certain amount of users.

Comment: That would not allow the user to dynamically add (or remove) `User` items n the view (only edit existing ones)

Comment: @StephenMuecke agreed, probably then it is better to use JS for handling dynamic adding/removing, which is pretty much covered by links you've pointed.