# How to do a model binding of an entity that contains a list of another entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want make a form using a model that contains a list of another entity, but I don't know how to do it. Note: without Entity Framework.

I have use only a model that contains only its fields, but not another entity.

My code is:

**Tarea.cs**

```
public class Tarea
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NombreTarea { get; set; }
    public int TiempoTarea { get; set; }
}
```

**Employee.cs**

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<Tarea> Tareas { get; set; }
}
```

And my view is:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@model MVCSimpleApp.Models.Employee
....
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Employee</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JoiningDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.JoiningDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JoiningDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Age, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Age, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Age, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I don't know how to put the `List<Tarea>` in the form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you wanting to dynamically add `Tarea` records in the view? If so, refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for some options

Comment: @StephenMuecke yes, I want to add Tarea dynamically.

Comment: do you want to show Tareas in drop down or in table or to create form..??

Comment: @Jilanipasha to create dynamically a set of inputs in the same form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Example, if we want to collect two sets of Tareas model,

**View Code:**

```
@for (var item = 0; item < 2; item++)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Tareas[item].ID)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tareas[item].NombreTarea, new { @class = "form-control" })
  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tareas[item].TiempoTarea, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```

And in the Post Create Action Method..

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Employee model)
{
  // here we we get the all values given from the view ...
  string example = model.Name;
  List<Tarea> list = model.Tareas; // and iterate through model.Tareas to get List model values
}
```

Comment: That is NOT the way to dynamically add new items to a collection (refer the links in the comments to the question for the correct approach)