# Collection with GUID id not binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a pretty simple pair of classes:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name ="Question Text")]
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer : IValidatableObject
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AnswerId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Answer Text")]
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Is Correct")]
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm trying to make an editor page the MVC way to edit both the question and the answers. So I have something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
   <input type="submit" value="Save Question" class="btn btn-default" />

   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionId)
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })

   <h4>Answers:</h4>
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Answers)
}
```

And a template for the `Answer` something like this:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AnswerId)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AnswerText, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsCorrect)
```

And loading the page everything looks good. I can see it's bound both the questions and the answers. But on submission, the `Question` object is populated, but `Answers` is null. But it looked like the submission did include all the fields I'd expect:

```
QuestionId:36
QuestionText:This is a test
Answers[0].AnswerId:0b5a2bdd-32fd-e711-93fc-b8ca3a683254
Answers[0].AnswerText:TRUE
Answers[0].IsCorrect:true
Answers[0].IsCorrect:false
Answers[1].AnswerId:0c5a2bdd-32fd-e711-93fc-b8ca3a683254
Answers[1].AnswerText:FALSE
Answers[1].IsCorrect:false
```

So what's going on here? From what I've read (a lot of it for previous versions of MVC) this should just work. Is it because of using a GUID as an id? What am I missing to make this bind properly?

Ultimately I'd like to be able to add and remove `Answers`, but one step at a time here.

EDIT: weirdly it is sending `Answers[0].IsCorrect` twice. Here's the generated HTML that it produced:

```
<input checked="checked" class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Is Correct field is required." id="Answers_0__IsCorrect" name="Answers[0].IsCorrect" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Answers[0].IsCorrect" type="hidden" value="false">
```

For the other answer (`Answer[1]`) it generates, which only results in one value for `Answers[1].IsCorrect`:

```
<input class="check-box" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Is Correct field is required." id="Answers_1__IsCorrect" name="Answers[1].IsCorrect" type="checkbox" value="true">
<input name="Answers[1].IsCorrect" type="hidden" value="false">
```

Comment: `Answers[0].IsCorrect:true Answers[0].IsCorrect:false` is this the actual data or just a mistake copy-pasting?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: I had to double check, and oddly, it really is there. But only for `[0]` and not `[1]`

Comment: I've never used EditorFor (I like being in control of the HTML), but check whether you have two `<input` with `name="Answers[0].IsCorrect"` on the generated HTML. The model binder might be having problems with that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It seems it produces a pair of `input` controls for each one. One is hidden and the other not. Maybe that's something to do with it, but I don't understand why it does it.

Comment: The 2 inputs for are generated to ensure a value is posted back (if its checked, it posts `true` and `false` (the `DefaultModelBinder` only binds the first one) and if its unchecked, it posts back `false` (because unchecked checkboxes do not submit a value)

Comment: The code you have shown works fine (although you did not show you POST method - it should be something like `public ActionResult Edit (Question model)`

Comment: As a side note, will not be able to use `EditorFor()` to generate you collection if your wanting to dynamically add and remove items. Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for some options you can use