# Editing childrens list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with adding/editing/deleting children list in parent object. In first method `Edit(int id)` I set current parent but while I'am adding new element of children list the `_currentParent` object is `null`. Do you have other idea to resolve this problem ?

```
public class Parent 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Children> Childrens { get; set; }
    public Parent()
    { 
       Childrens = new List<Children>();
    }

}

public class Children
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ParentController : Controller
{   
        private Parent _currentParent 
...
        public ViewResult Edit(int id)
        {
            var parent = _ParentsRepository.Find(id);
            _currentParent = parent;
        }

        public ViewResult AddChildren(string name)
        {
            _currentParent.Childrens.Add(new Children(){Name = name});
        }
...
}
```

Comment: But currently parent object has the list of childrens.

Comment: It is not a good design for children to know about parent and parent know about children. It should probably be one or the other, not both.

Comment: The web is stateless. Every request create a new instance of the controller which initializes `_currentParent` as `null`

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: Pass the value of the `parentId` to your `AddChildren()` method then create and save the `Children` object to your db.

Comment: I want first add children elements and on "Save" button save all.

Comment: @Szymson. Then add all the child elements in your `Edit` view (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for one option for doing that)

Comment: I don't have BeginCollectionItem method on Html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164936/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-szymson).

Answer (score 0):

I would do a null check in the Edit method to verify that parent variable is not null. If it is null, then it means that there is no object that has the given id.

Comment: But in debug in Edit method _currentTemplate is not null.