# Bind model with array property to form in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to figure out how to bind form elements to model containing a property that is an array or enumerable. This form should be usable for adding a new object or editing an existing one.

Below is a stripped down example.

If Levels contains no elements (e.g. create), the row of Level fields is not rendered. Should you add an empty element to the Level array or should you add a row of empty fields? But how to do this using the asp-for attribute.

If Levels contains elements (e.g. edit), the rows of Level fields is rendered. However, when posting `model.Levels` in the `Edit` method is `null`.

Any ideas how to best implement this?

Model to bind

```
public class CarparkModel
{
  [HiddenInput]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Level[] Levels { get; set; }
}

public class Level
{
   [HiddenInput]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public int NrOfSpaces { get; set; }
}
```

Main view

```
@model CarparkModel

<form method="POST">
  <input asp-for="Id">
  <div>
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name">
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Nr of spaces</th>
    </tr>
  @foreach (Level level in Model.Levels)
  {
    <tr>
      <td><input asp-for="Description"></td>
      <td><input asp-for="NrOfSpaces"></td>
    </tr>
  }
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2>
        <!-- Click = new row of Level fields added -->
        <button type="button">Add level</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Controller

```
public class CarparkController
{
  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Create()
  {
    return View(new CarparkModel());
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Create(CarparkModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _repository.Save(model);
      return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    return View(model);    
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Edit(int id)
  {
    return View(_repository.Get(id));
  }

  [HttpPost]
  public IActionResult Edit(CarparkModel model)
  {
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
      _repository.Save(model);
      return RedirectToAction("index");
    }

    return View(model);    
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `foreach` if you want to be able to send the items back in the form. use `for` loop with indexed naming for the items.

Comment: If you wanting to dynamically add new items to the collection, then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for some options, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892) for a detailed implementation using `BeginCollectionItem`.

Comment: Since you using core-mvc, you will need to use [this version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BeginCollectionItemCore) of `BeginCollectionItem`

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `foreach` if you want to be able to send the items back in the form. use `for` loop with indexed naming for the items.

```html
@model CarparkModel

<form method="POST">
  <input asp-for="Id">
  <div>
    <label asp-for="Name"></label>
    <input asp-for="Name">
  </div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Nr of spaces</th>
    </tr>
  @for(var index = 0, index < Model.Levels.Length, index++)
  {
    <tr>
      <td><input asp-for="@Model.Levels[index].Description"></td>
      <td><input asp-for="@Model.Levels[index].NrOfSpaces"></td>
    </tr>
  }
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <!-- Click = new row of Level fields added -->
        <button type="button">Add level</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

The index is needed to reconstruct the collection when posting it in the form.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me an answer to part of the problem. Now I need to tackle the issue of binding fields for an empty array.

Comment: Would be nice if [index] was optional, instead [] could be used... makes adding/deleting items with javascript a pain...