# Bootstrap 4 modal not working/showing inside BeginCollectionItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

My modal inside `BegiCollectionItem` functions is not working/showing, How can I fix this issue?

Here is my code:

//other tds here

```
 @model SimplyAccounting.Models.TransactionViewModels.JournalDetailsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("JournalDetailsViewModel"))
{
        <td>
            <a class="btn btn-sm" role="button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#@Model.Guid">Others</a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="@Model.Guid" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        //content here
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" id="delete" name="delete" value="delete" onclick="javascript: deleteBook(document.getElementById('@Model.Guid'))"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why its not working? Does it end up with an error or something!? You may like to provide more information!

Comment: @DarkSuniuM, nothing happens, no error in console

Comment: Then how u realize it's not working!?

Comment: @DarkSuniuM no modal showing

Comment: Having a model inside a `Html.BeginCollectionItem()` makes no sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, user can add/remove details before inserting to db

Comment: But what is the modal for? (if you want to understand how to add/delete items in the collection, refer [A Partial View passing a collection using the Html.BeginCollectionItem helper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40539321/partial-view-passing-a-collection-using-the-html-begincollectionitem-helper/40541892#40541892))

Comment: some other details, per row contains more than 10 textboxes, I want to only show important textboxes and hide the less important to modal

Comment: It makes no sense to be using a model inside `BeginCollectionItem` (and you certainly would not have a modal for each item anyway)